# How i can get the total number of child threads running under one process?

Tags: java, process

I have a code that gives me the list of process running on my computer.

```
     String line;
     Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec
        (System.getenv("windir") +"\\system32\\"+"tasklist.exe");
     BufferedReader input =
            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
     while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
     System.out.println(line);
```

This code give the list of running processes.

Suppose i am running 2 Notepads , then it will give two rows having notepad.exe.

But suppose i have opened two word documents,then there will be only one `word.exe` .
Since in this case there are two child threads opening under one process.

So my question is how i can get the total number of child threads running under one process?

Comment: Two `notepad.exe` means two processes, not one. So what do you want really?

Comment: @khachik ya.i agree.But in case of word (MS WORD) , it is threads.So suppose i a have open 5 word documents, so i want to get the tolal number of threads in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this with pslist.exe from sysinternals

http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/bb896682

e.g. pslist -x chrome get's you all threads from all chrome processes

Calling pslist.exe and retrieving the result can be done analogous to calling tasklist.exe.

Comment: Thanks.How i can copy pslist.exe to system32 directory?

Comment: You mustn't copy it to the system32 directory. You can copy it to your working directory, from where you start your java programm and run it with 'Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("pslist -x");'

Comment: Ya.You are right.It will work.But if i will copy pslist.exe to system32 directory, then there will be no condition that pslist.exe should be present where my java program resides.

Comment: Sure, but you have to install it into the system32 directory, which may be write protected for your user. Or your customer doesn't want to change something in this directory. I prefer my programms to be as much selfcontained as possible. Anyway: What was your problem with copying the file into system32?

Comment: It gave error that you dont have persmission to write into the folder.

Comment: Since Windows Vista there's a security concept named UAC which prohibits access to system folders. You can switch this of, but there are good reasons not to modify system folders. I would stick to distributing pslist.exe with my program. regards Andreas